# Get the values for a specific attribute from a product ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I am trying to get products custom attribute with options values. This is how I get a normal attribute:

```
$myproducts['data']['discount'] = $product->get_attribute('pa_discount');
```

Does somebody have any idea how I get my attribute Size with options S, M and L?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment, you are using nearly the right way, but to get your attibute values you don't need **`array_shift()`** php function here, as you will get only the first listed value for that attribute.

You can use instead a foreach loop to get each value for example:

```
foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_size' ) as $attribute_value ){
    // Outputting the attibute values one by one
    echo $attribute_value . '<br>';
}
```

Or you can use also implode() php function to get a coma separated string of that values:

```
echo implode(', ', wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, 'pa_size' ));
```

This code works…

Comment: `echo implode(', ', wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, 'pa_size' )); ` 
this displays "Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string"

Comment: the same first variant. The problem in echo.
Should be given any key on object, for example if needs to display attribute names:


`foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_size' ) as $attribute_value ){
    // Outputting the attibute values one by one
    echo $attribute_value->name . '<br>';
}`